# Allocation i deleting 2d array with pointer

Tags: c

I don't know what I am doing wrong. I have that main():

```
int main(int argc, char argv[])
{

    Player ** player = NULL;
    int sizePlayer = STARTPLAYER;

    CreateMemoryPlayer(&player,sizePlayer);    

    DeleteMemoryPlayer(&player, sizePlayer);
    return 0;
}
```

And this is the Create function:

```
void CreateMemoryPlayer(Player *** player,int size)
{
    Player ** tmpPlayer = *player;

    tmpPlayer = (Player **)calloc(size, sizeof(Player*));
    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
        tmpPlayer[i] = (Player*)calloc(1, sizeof(Player));
}
```

Delete:

```
void DeleteMemoryPlayer(Player *** player,int size)
{
    Player ** tmpPlayer = *player;
    for (int i = 0; i <size ; i++)
        free(tmpPlayer[i]);
    free(tmpPlayer);
}
```

I thing it's good, but programme crashing. I don't really know what maybe wrong in this code. Help me, please.

Comment: You should use `size_t` for sizes. And don't cast the return value of `malloc` or `calloc` or `realloc` in C.

Comment: Check the value of `player` in the main. Did it change?

Comment: In the function Create must be mistake, because programme don't pass after this function.

Comment: 1) Being as 3-star C-programmer is not a compliment. It usually means you messed the interface up. 2) Why do you think a _function_ can **return** a value? 3) There is no 2D array in your code. A pointer is not an array! 4) Do not cast the result of `malloc` & friends or `void *` in general in C! 5) Learn [ask] and provide a [mcve].

Comment: 6) Provide a link to that "C/C++" language. Until then, there are just the two **different** languages C and C++. Don't add unrelated tags.

Comment: `argv` should be `char *argv[]` or `char **argv`, not `char argv[]`

Answer (score 1):

If I see this correctly, the memory allocated in CreateMemoryPlayer() is only assigned to the local variable `tmpPlayer`, but you never update the argument variable `player` which is needed to pass the reference to the allocated memory back to the main() method.

A better pattern would be to write the two methods such that they can be used like this:

```
Player ** player = CreateMemoryPlayer(sizePlayer);
DeleteMemoryPlayer(player, sizePlayer);
```

Comment: It may be worth adding to this that the initialization `tmpPlayer = *player` assigns the (garbage) value of whatever `player` was pointing to at the beginning of the function.

Comment: God, I knew It's simple problem. Thank you

Answer (score 1):

You should return the `Player` array, instead of passing it by pointer.

```
Player **creatplayer(size_t size)
{
    Player **ret;
    size_t i;

    if ((ret = calloc(1, sizeof (Player *))) == NULL)
        return NULL;

    for (i = 0; i < size; ++i)
        if ((ret[i] = calloc(1, sizeof (Player))) == NULL)
            return NULL;

    return ret;
}
void delplayer(Player **p, size_t size)
{
    size_t i;
    for (i = 0; i < size; ++i)
        free(p[i]);
    free(p);
}
```